# Elasticsearch high memory usage

Tags: elasticsearch

Iam using elasticsearch on our development machine currently. Be we want to move productive in a few weeks. Today i typed "top" and i was shocked what i was seeing.

```
 PID   USER      PR   NI  VIRT  RES   SHR S  %CPU %MEM    TIME+   COMMAND
 28972 elastics  20   0   27.4g 1.4g  39m S  186  4.3     2:11.19 java
```

Is this normal for elasticsearch to use so much memory. I never configured something that way.
What is the perfect configuration if we have up to 5 indices on one machine with 32 GB of RAM.
How many Replicas/Shards should i configure?
How can i control the memory usage?

I dont want to get the same problems we have with Solr => Unexpected Shutdowns.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: which version of ES are you using??

Answer (score 5):

After Es 1.0 version. the default file storage mode is [Mmapfs](http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/mlockall-and-mmapfs-store-type-clarification-td4039211.html).the mamapfs stores data in HD.But it use virtual memory concept.though data are present in HD,it looks like fetching data from RAM.It is more faster than other file system.

So the mmapfs might look consuming more space and It blocks some address space.But its is healthy and no problem at all.

To configure **optimal no of shards and replicas** [refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22544461/elasticsearch-optimal-number-of-shards-per-node/22558656#22558656).

To get rid of Unexpected shutdowns and data loss .configure following terms..

1) **ulimit** for no of file to be open for certain user must increase as much as can.

2) No of threads should be pre configured..following are some example configurations

```
    # Search pool
threadpool.search.type: fixed
threadpool.search.size: 5
threadpool.search.queue_size: 200

# Bulk pool
threadpool.bulk.type: fixed
threadpool.bulk.size: 5
threadpool.bulk.queue_size: 300

# Index pool
threadpool.index.type: fixed
threadpool.index.size: 5
threadpool.index.queue_size: 200

# Indices settings
indices.memory.index_buffer_size: 30%
indices.memory.min_shard_index_buffer_size: 12mb
indices.memory.min_index_buffer_size: 96mb

# Cache Sizes
indices.fielddata.cache.size: 15%
indices.fielddata.cache.expire: 6h
indices.cache.filter.size: 15%
indices.cache.filter.expire: 6h

# Indexing Settings for Writes
index.refresh_interval: 30s
index.translog.flush_threshold_ops: 50000
```

Comment: Like MongoDB does? (I mean a kind of mapping between RAM and HD data)

Comment: "Number of threads should be pre configured."? http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_don_8217_t_touch_these_settings.html#_threadpools