# How does storage beign used in elasticsearch 2.x

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch 2.x . I have total 9 nodes with M4.4xlarge and I want to downsize to lesser nodes . 
Total docs I need to store 2 Million
Per doc size = 30KB
With this stats I Believe Elasticsearch would need

30 KB * 2000000 docs  = 60000000 KB = 60000 = 60GB ~

However when I have indexed all docs I see its 500GB data. 
I am confused as how my index has grown this much
could someone please give me some insights to work upon

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Elastic search disc space calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26379293/elastic-search-disc-space-calculation)

Comment: 60GB is the size of your **raw data**. Then the storage requirements depend on many other factors, among which: how many replica shards do you have? how is your data analyzed? Are you using index compression?

Comment: I think I got the gist. Replica shards are playing role here . Yes you are right @Val . so 60GB * 5 = 300 GB is already consumed and beyond this analyzer is taking more space. no my  data is not compressed

Comment: yes . thanks for super fast response.. appreciate Stack over flow community :)