# Elasticsearch - general architecture and Elastic Cloud questions

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-cloud

### Background

We're designing the architecture of a new system using Elasticsearch now, and we plan to use Elastic Cloud based on reviews contrasting their service with AWS's, and self-hosting on an EC2 instance. As we design the system, I'm trying to learn from a small test project my team deployed on Elastic Cloud 6 months ago. While I've spent a lot of time reading the [Elasticsearch Docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index.html), [Elasticsearch: The Definitive Guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index.html), and [Elastic Cloud's Docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/index.html), there are some concepts here that I'm still not understanding.

### Our Test Project's issues

Our test project uses the default of 5 primary shards and 1 replica shard per primary. It was configured using the default deployment options on Elastic Cloud with a single one node, currently with 2GB of memory. Because there is only one node, and because replica shards are never assigned to the same node as their primary shard ([reason 2](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/elasticsearch-unassigned-shards/)), none of the replicas are getting assigned. Also, this project uses [time-based data](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/time-based.html), and is creating one index per account per day, resulting in about 10 indexes per day (or 100 shards), and over time, the proverbial [Kagillion Shards](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/kagillion-shards.html). This system was only ever meant to have several months of data on it at a time, so the solution has been to manually delete old data when memory on this deployment runs out.

### The New System

Our new system is meant to have 5 years worth of time based-data on it, which is projected to grow to 250 GB in size.  The current implementation uses a single index for the time-based data, with 6 primary shards and 1 replica per primary. This decision was made based on reading that a single shard should aim for a maximum of 30GB in size.

### Questions

1. Our old system had one node with too many indexes (over 100) and too many shards (over 1000), and it seems like our new one is being designed with too few (one index for 5+ years of data). It seems a better indexing strategy according to the [time-based data](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/time-based.html) recommendations would be to create one index per week or month? That being said, according to [another answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27865188/510173) the optimal number of indexes per node is 1, so what is the utility in creating multiple indices for time-based data in the first place if we're only running on one node?
2. How does one add a node to an ES deployment in Elastic Cloud? Currently all of the replica nodes in the test project are unassigned, because the deployment only has one node. There is a slider which allows you to easily choose the memory of each node in a deployment (between 1GB and 250B), however I see no way to add multiple nodes, which is confusing because it seems like basic functionality for Elasticsearch.
3. Our test project's node has restarted several times, always when there is lots of old data on the node, and therefore memory pressure. The solution has been to delete old data (as the test project was only meant to have several months of data at a time), but it appears the node didn't lose data when it restarted. Why would this be?
4. Our test project has taken no snapshots, which are supposed to happen automatically on Elastic Cloud every 30 minutes. I've asked their support about this, but just curious to see if anyone knows what could cause this and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Our test project uses the default of 5 primary shards and 1 replica shard per primary. It was configured using the default deployment options on Elastic Cloud with a single one node

Clearly, on a single node, you cannot have replicas. So your index should have been configured with 0 replicas and you can do it dynamically to get your cluster back to green (`PUT index/_settings {"index.number_of_replicas": 0}`), simple as that.

> Also, this project uses time-based data, and is creating one index per account per day, resulting in about 10 indexes per day (or 100 shards)

I cannot tell if 50 new primary shards (10 index) per day were reasonable or not because you don't give any information regarding the volume of data in your test project. But it's probably too many.

> 1. It seems a better indexing strategy according to the time-based data recommendations would be to create one index per week or month?

Having five years worth of data in a single index is perfectly possible, it doesn't really depend on how old the data is, but on how big it grows. You mention 250GB and also that you know a shard shouldn't grow over 30GB (and that again depends on the spec of your hardware underneath, more on that later), but since you have only 6 shards for that index, it means that each shard will grow over 40GB (which is ok according to [this](https://www.elastic.co/blog/how-many-shards-should-i-have-in-my-elasticsearch-cluster)), but to be on the safe side, you should probably increase to 8-9 shards, or you split your data into yearly/monthly indices.

The 30GB-ish limit per shard is also dependent on how much heap your nodes have. If you have nodes with 2GB heap, then having 30GB shards is clearly too big. Since you're on ES Cloud and you plan to have 250GB of data, you must have chosen a node capacity of 16GB heap + 384GB storage (or bigger). So with 16GB heap, it's reasonable to have 30GB shards, but you'll need several nodes in my opinion. You can verify how many nodes you have using `GET _cat/nodes?v`.

> 1. That being said, according to another answer on SO the optimal number of indexes per node is 1...

What Chris is saying is a theoretical/ideal setting, which is almost never possible/advisable/desired to do in reality. You do want to have several shards in your index and the reason is that when your data grows, you want to be able to scale to more than one node, that's the whole point of ES, otherwise you'd be better off embedding the Lucene library directly in your project.

> 1. ..., so what is the utility in creating multiple indices for time-based data in the first place if we're only running on one node?

First check how many nodes you have in your cluster using `GET _cat/nodes?v`, but clearly if you're assigned a single node for 250GB of data split on 6-8 shards, a single node is not ideal, indeed.

> 2. How does one add a node to an ES deployment in Elastic Cloud?

Right now, you can't. However, at the last Elastic{ON} conference, [Elastic announced](https://www.elastic.co/elasticon/conf/2018/sf/elastic-cloud-next) that it will be possible to pick the number of nodes or the kind of deployment (hot/warm, etc) you want to set up.

> 2. Currently all of the replica nodes in the test project are unassigned, because the deployment only has one node.

You don't really need replicas in a test project, right?

> 3. The solution has been to delete old data (as the test project was only meant to have several months of data at a time), but it appears the node didn't lose data when it restarted. Why would this be?

How did you delete the data? Between the time you deleted the data and before the node restarted, did you witness that the data was indeed gone?

> 4. Our test project has taken no snapshots, which are supposed to happen automatically on Elastic Cloud every 30 minutes.

This is weird, since on ES cloud your cluster generally gets snapshotted every 30 minutes. What do you see under Deployments > cluster-id > Elasticsearch > Snapshots? What does the ES Cloud support say about it? What do you get when running `GET _cat/repositories?v` and `GET _cat/snapshots/found-snapshots?v`? (update your question with the results)

Comment: Thanks!! 1) We have moved to monthly indexes and single replica shards spread out over two nodes. 2) Elastic Cloud support confirmed you get a second node when you add a second AZ (since it requires a new VM/node, which somehow wasn't obvious to me before) or when you increase your memory size beyond 64GB, as that is their max node size currently. 3) The test project had over 1500+ primary shards (and 1500 unassigned replicas) on a single 2GB node, which is what caused the memory pressure / restarts. 4) Support confirmed that this is weird/unexplained, and they were able to turn them back on.

Comment: 2) correct, I should have mentioned AZs, however, I thought you were asking whether you could specify how many nodes you wanted to have just from within the configuration, which is not possible right now.